# How to send JSON object inside the http_request and how to access it on the server?

Tags: c++, json, rest

I created a listener with C++ REST SDK (casablanca).I need to create a http server which it should read the JSON object which is embedded inside the request message body.How to achieve this? Im trying to do it  via Put method. But I couldn't find a way to extract the request message body. It is better if I can convert that json object in to string inside the put method in order to print it. But I couldn't find a way to do that. Is there any possible way to access that json object and convert it to string?

this is the method I'm trying.

```
void WsListener::handle_put(http_request message)
{
    cout << message.body.extract_json();

};
```

Comment: http://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1json_1_1value.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void WsListener::handle_put(http_request message)
{
    pplx::task<utility::string_t> body_json = message.extract_string();
            std::string jsonstr=    utility::conversions::to_utf8string(body_json.get());
            cout << jsonstr << endl;

};
```

http://microsoft.github.io/cpprestsdk/classweb_1_1http_1_1http__request.html#a0cd0f1c49cab39210517925a3644db1f